ngrok not working in mac, error 3617 killed in mac
I tried tunneling port 3000, but it killed itself. also tired uninstalling and reinstalling ngrok, it executed successfully, but then it killed itself. When I tried running the same command again, it showed 'command not found'.
› ngrok http 3000 [1]  
  3617 killed     ngrok http 3000  

› ngrok http 3000
 zsh: command not found: ngrok

I tried to install ngrok, but it isn't working properly. Could someone please advise me on how to diagnose the issue and understand what's going on under the hood?

Had the same problem, any solutions?

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [apple.se] would be better places for questions like this.

@Petruza Turn off your antivirus and then install it again.

After troubleshooting, I found that the issue was caused by Microsoft Defender on my machine. Here's what worked for me:

Turn Off Microsoft Defender:

Temporarily disable Microsoft Defender's real-time protection.
Run the ngrok command again, and it should work.


Add Ngrok to Exclusions (Optional):

To prevent future interference, add ngrok to the exclusion list in Defender.



Note:
If you still encounter issues, check your antivirus or firewall settings on macOS or any other system. Tools like Gatekeeper, Microsoft Defender, or other security software may misidentify ngrok as a threat and interfere with its functionality.

I had similar issue. The ngrok binary would be deleted when run.
I did the following and all was good:
Download ngrok from the official website
curl -O https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-v3-stable-darwin-amd64.zip

Unzip the downloaded file
unzip ngrok-stable-darwin-amd64.zip

Move the ngrok binary to /usr/local/bin
sudo mv ngrok /usr/local/bin/ngrok

Make the ngrok binary executable
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ngrok

Run ngrok
ngrok http 80

--
MacOS Sonama 14.7, M1.
